# OData batch in asp.net core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I'm trying to implement batching in my api by leveraging the OData batch endpoint. Please note that I'm not interested in using OData query/select/etc. Just use the batch endpoint to batch queries/updates.

I setup everything as following:

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options.AddRouteComponents("api", new EdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler()))
```

and

```
app.UseODataBatching();
app.MapControllers();
```

Batch requests are somewhat working. Requests to /api/$batch works, but all the inner requests always return 404.

It looks like the batch handler is not resolving the inner actions.

```
Request:
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "id":"1234",
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"api/i18n",
      "headers":{
        "accept":"application/json",
        "content-type":"application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
Response:
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "status": 404,
      "headers": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Calling `/$odata` endpoint returns a list of empty OData Endpoint Mappings, and a list of all my Non-OData Endpoint Mappings (where api/i18n is included). Adding `EnableQuery` to the action makes no difference.

I also tried to register routes/controllers in the old way

```
app.UseRouting()
app.UseODataRouteDebug();
app.UseODataBatching();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

But again, same results.

Any idea if this could work in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable batch middleware to pipeline before `UseRouting()` middleware:

```
app.UseODataBatching();
app.UseRouting();
```

If you can directly access the corresponding information through `api/i18n`, then when you request `/api/$batch`, the url you provide should be `i18n`, not `api/i18n`:

```
{
    "requests":[
        {
          //...
          "url":"i18n",
          //...
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/renukapatil-21/ODATA-Student-API), you can refer to it. The corresponding explanation is [here](https://dev.to/renukapatil/supercharging-aspnet-60-with-odata-crud-batching-pagination-12np).